# HTML alt text for image maps

Tags: html, image, imagemap, alt

So the image itself can be given alternate text in cases that it won't load, but what about image maps?

Is there any way to create backup text links for every image mapped area, should the image itself not load?

```html
<map id="knightmap" name="knightmap">
 <!--Hilt--><area shape="circle" coords="201,361 11" 
href="http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/HowTo:End_Him_Rightly"/>
 <!--Banner--><area shape="rect" coords="278,309 351,636" 
href="http://www.medievalchronicles.com/medieval-knights/knights-coat-of- 
arms/"/>
 <!--Sword--><area shape="poly" coords="195,335 157,346 112,303 149,271 
95,10 125,5 172,150 200,261 220,324 " 
href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightly_sword"/>
 <!--Shield--><area shape="poly" coords="346,231 415,210 485,212 480,367 
441,482 418,487" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_shield"/>
 <!--Helm--><area shape="poly" coords="300,300 204,250 197,231 200,225 
190,180 204,136 245,83 323,135 334,182 353,192 353,209 " 
href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_helmet"/>
 <!--Boot left--><area shape="poly" coords="203,597 226,604 228,614 195,627 
145,630 143,620" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabaton"/>
 <!--Boot right--><area shape="poly" coords="434,700 450,687 491,704 488,719 
433,719 " href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabaton"/>
</map>

<img src="images/lab9/knight.png" usemap="knightmap" class="center" 
alt="Knight"/>
```

Comment: I don't know, but `title` is available on all HTML elements, being a *universal attribute*.

Answer (score 0):

If an [`area` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-area-element) has an `href` attribute, it **must** have an `alt` attribute:

> It specifies the text of the hyperlink. Its value must be text that informs the user about the destination of the link.

So the `img`-`alt` describes the image, the `area`-`alt` describes the content of the linked page. You can find [an example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element-image-maps) in the spec:

> ```
> <p>View houses for sale in North Katoomba or South Katoomba:</p>
> <p><img src="imagemap.png" width="209" alt="Map of Katoomba" height="249" usemap="#Map">
>
> <map name="Map">
>   <area shape="poly" coords="78,124,124,10,189,29,173,93,168,132,136,151,110,130" href="north.html" alt="Houses in North Katoomba">
>   <area shape="poly" coords="66,63,80,135,106,138,137,154,167,137,175,133,144,240,49,223,17,137,17,61" alt="Houses in South Katoomba" href="south.html">
> </map>
> ```